# document.ready and ajax

Tags: jquery, document-ready

let's say that I using this code and I want to change it after an ajax call (change fx for example).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideshow').cycle({
      fx: 'fade' ,
      timeout: 1500
    });

}}
```

is it possible ?

thanks

Comment: When posting questions specific to a plug-in (`cycle` isn't core jQuery), it's best to link to the site for the plug-in. In this case, you'll want to look at the plug-in's documentation to see if there's a way to change the options it's using while it's running (or a way to stop it, then start again).

Comment: What happens if you just try to call the code again with a different fx? I would have thought that would just override the previous cycle. That's just a general assumption though, I have no idea about this specific code.

Answer (score 2):

If the `.cycle()` method allows you to call it again with new parameters, you could use something like:

```
$.ajax(
  ...
  // do your ajax stuff here
  ...
).done(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({ fx: 'newfx', timeout: 500} );
});
```

This will then be executed after the AJAX call, independent of the outcome.
If you only want it to execute after a **successful** AJAX call, use

```
$.ajax(
  ...
  // do your ajax stuff here
  ...
  .success (function() {
    // do other stuff here, if necessary
    $('.slideshow').cycle({ fx: 'newfx', timeout: 500} );
 });
```